# Мне нужно ускорить рекурсию

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Мне задали решить задачу. Я написал код, но он работает медленно. Мне нужно ускорить рекурсию. Если `n` будет равен даже 70 расчеты займет очень много времени.
Помогите мне улучшить мой код. Максимальное n может быть 500!

```
def a(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 2
    return 1 + a(n - a(a(n - 1)))
```

Comment: вы бы еще сказали что эта рекурсия делает, может можно было бы обойтись и без рекурсии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как вариант -

дело в том, что функция `a(n)` вызывается многократно, а значит рекурсий больше, чем нужно

можно вычислить `a(n)` однократно и дальше только использовать уже вычисленные значения

```
res = [0 for _ in range(1000)]

def a(n):
    if res[n] == 0:
        if n > 2:
            res[n] = 1 + a(n - a(a(n - 1)))
        elif n == 1:
            res[n] = 1
        elif n == 2:
            res[n] = 2

    return res[n]

print(a(900))
```

`a(900)` работает мгновенно, так что можно считать это оптимизацией :)

только учтите одну важную вещь, я не знаю как у питона, но при рекурсии у того же c++ вызовы запихиваются в стек и стек может просто переполниться

в моем примере при n = 1000 питон уже ругается

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

**P.S.**

в коде много if, поэтому лучше сделать ее покороче

```
res = [0, 1, 2] + [0 for _ in range(10)]

def a(n):
    if res[n] == 0:
        res[n] = 1 + a(n - a(a(n - 1)))

    return res[n]


print(a(10))
```

да и вообще зачем нам эти if?

```
res = [0, 1, 2] + [0 for _ in range(20)]

def a(n):
    res[n] = res[n] or (1 + a(n - a(a(n - 1))))
    return res[n]

print(res)
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо,, как раз в условиях задачи написано максимальное n, может быть 500. Теперь буду знать :)

Comment: опять же - если бы на счету стояла каждая наносекунда, то код можно еще соптимизировать, чтобы не вызывать так много рекурсий,

Comment: Ну лимит времени 10 секунд, так что всё окей :)

Comment: @Zhihar Вы же понимаете, что в последнем фрагменте кода будут проблемы когда рекурсия дойдёт до `a(0)`? )  `0 or ...`  Всегда надо код проверять, не вызвали, не проверили - а грабли тут как тут )

Comment: @CrazyElf, не будет, потому что дойдет только или до 1 или до 2, до 0 не дойдет, но вообще я изначально думал вместо `0` везде None поставить, если так можно конечно

Comment: @Zhihar А, я не прав, не с тем параметром вызывал. Хм...

Answer (score 1):

Здесь есть простой способ ускорения: кешировние Завести глобальный массив, и при вычислении функции от какого то значения аргумента записывать туда результат. При следующем вызове функциии от того же значения аргумента -  не вычислять её, а брать из массива готовое, уже посчитанное значение

Comment: Ага я буду сидеть 3 часа и делать всё if-ами.

Comment: В соседнем ответе @Zhihar справился за 9 минут и обошелся двумя дополнительными if -ами. И сделал ровно то, что я написал словми

Comment: Я просто не понял , что вы имели ввиду, я новенький просто, спасибо.

Comment: @S.H. - эээээээ я справился за минуту :) а остальное время ушло на написание комментария и проверки где же питон перестанет рекурсить :)))

Comment: @S.H. вы правы, что-то много я if поставил, в своем ответе уменьшил их кол-во

Comment: @Zhihar - просто круто! дело боится мастера панически!

Comment: @S.H. оказалось, что можно вообще без if :) попробовал javascript подход использовать

Comment: @Zhihar - уже почти "программистский гольф" :-)

Comment: @Zhihar. Жесть, ещё учиться и учиться.